# Accessing .NET components from Powershell

Tags: powershell, components

I want to use Powershell to write some utilities, leveraging our own .NET components to handle the actual work.  This is in place of writing a small console app to tie the calls together.  My question is where I would find a good source of documentation or tutorial material to help me fast track this?

Comment: Do you need info about simply using .Net assemblies in powershell, or are you looking for info on writing assemblies that are more powershell friendly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to load an assembly into your PowerShell session, you can use reflection and load the assembly.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(PathToYourAssembly)
```

After you load your assembly, you can call static methods and create new instances of a class.

A good tutorial can be found [here](http://stevenmurawski.com/powershell/2009/03/exploring-the-net-framework-with-powershell-constructors-part-3/).

Both books mentioned by EBGreen are excellent.  The PowerShell Cookbook is very task oriented and PowerShell in Action is a great description of the language, its focus and useability.  PowerShell in Action is one of my favorite books. :)

Comment: @Sung Thanks, I'm actually working on a series about using .NET from PowerShell on my blog - http://blog.usepowershell.com/category/net-framework/introduction/

Comment: :/ links are dead, can you update them? here's another one I found http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/29/how-to-load-net-assemblies-in-a-powershell-session/ useful

Comment: Link is inaccessible (no permission).

Answer (score 4):

The link that Steven posted is a good example. I don't know of any extensive tutorial. Both the [Windows Powershell Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596528492/) and [Windows Powershell In Action](http://www.manning.com/payette/) have good chapters on the subject. Also, look at the ::LoadFromFile method of the System.Reflection.Assembly class in case your in-house assemblies are not loaded in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[]` or use `add-type -AssemblyName "System.example"`  to use assembly for example use :

```
[system.drawing]::class ...
```