# Beanshell equivalent for .Net

Tags: .net, clr, beanshell

Is there anything like Beanshell, which exposes CLR classes instead of Java classes, and lets you write scripts in C# or VB.Net (or any .Net language for that matter)

Should come in handy to test one-liner code snippets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx) lets you do this.

See [Accessing .NET components from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123/accessing-net-components-from-powershell)

Comment: Powershell is indeed good option, though I wish it offered a syntax options of being C#-like and VB-like rather than it's current syntax. Beanshell at least has or can use Java-like syntax.