# Logging from powershell-script to csharp-program (log4net - logfile)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, log4net

I have written a program with C#, that creates a logfile and fills this by using log4net. This program starts powershell-scripts. The scripts should use log4net, too. I want to monitor what the scripts log to log4net while they are running and write this information in my logfile.

Have you an idea how I do this or where I get information/help to my problem?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define some functions and pass them to your script as variables:

```
    static void Log(string message) {
        // log4net code here...
    }

    void ExecuteScript() {

        // create the runspace configuration
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

        // create the runspace, open it and add variables for the script
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();

        // pass the Log function as a variable
        runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Log", (Action<string>)Log);
        // etc...
```

Then you can invoke the function from the script like this:

```
$Log.Invoke("test")
```

**EDIT**: to add a logging level, you should do something like

```
    static void Log(LogLevel level,string message) {
        // log4net code here...
    }

     void ExecuteScript() {
        // ...
        runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Log", (Action<LogLevel,string>)Log);
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like very good. Unfortunately I have problems to use the code for me ($Log.Invoke(""): Can I say what log-level I need? ...) Have you found an interesting website where I can find more information? thank you.

Comment: OK. It doesn´t work in my code. So I have still two question to your code: What namespace is the "LogLevel". I have found: GemStone.GemFire.Cache on http://www.gemstone.com/docs/5.7.0/product/native_client/docs/sandcastle-CSharp/html/2A875BE3.htm!                                    What do Action? I can only find a delegate-method.                thank you.

Comment: @Rotaney: I don't know log4net, it was just an example of how to add a parameter to your function. An alternative could be having more than one function (Info, Warning, Error etc) and pass all those functions to your script.

Comment: Cool stuff, but unfortunately this does not work for PSRemoting, because of serialization. Is there still a way of doing this with PSRemoting?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative you could reroute the streams and use the standard Write-Error, Write-Verbose, etc. CMDlets in your Script.

In your C# app attach methods to the streams events, like so:

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
// ... code to add your script, etc.
ps.Streams.Warning.DataAdded += new EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs>(Warning_DataAdded);
// ... attach more streams for other log levels
ps.Invoke();
```

Create your methods like so:

```
static void Warning_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    PSDataCollection<WarningRecord> warningStream = (PSDataCollection<WarningRecord>)sender;
    log.Warn(warningStream[e.Index].Message);
}
```

This should write everything you output in your PowerShell Script via

```
Write-Warning "This is a warning message"
```

to the Warn level in log4net.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have details specific to log4net but it should be possible to load log4net like any other .Net component:

[Accessing .NET components from Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123/accessing-net-components-from-powershell)
[Powershell Calling .NET Assembly that uses App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835862/powershell-calling-net-assembly-that-uses-app-config)