# Importing Jar classes in powershell

Tags: powershell

There is java package which I want to import in my powershell script and use the classes available in the package.
Can someone help me achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is based on the .NET runtime. (See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell).) You cannot use Java classes in it. You may, however, use .NET classes. They can be loaded as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26123/accessing-net-components-from-powershell).

Your options are basically:

- Find a .NET equivalent. There is often one available, actually.
- Write a Java program and execute it using the Java runtime. (`java.exe MyClass` or whatever command would be used to run it.)